# How to add background image with ngStyle?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to populate multiple cards as following:

```
<mdl-card *ngFor="let product of templates" class="demo-card-event" mdl-shadow="2" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': 'lightgray' }">
    <mdl-card-title mdl-card-expand>
        <h4>
            {{product.name}}
        </h4>
    </mdl-card-title>
    <mdl-card-actions mdl-card-border>
        <button mdl-button mdl-colored mdl-ripple (click)="booknow()">
            Show
        </button>
        <mdl-layout-spacer></mdl-layout-spacer>
        <mdl-icon>event</mdl-icon>
    </mdl-card-actions>
</mdl-card>
```

Here css gets applied dynamically i.e. background-color changes to lightgrey. However what I actually want is to apply `background: url(-- here I want product.img --)` where in my object array templates each object has property img which contains url.

How can I update my statement in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it as the following:

```
<div ...[ngStyle]="{background: 'url('+ product.image+')'"....>
```

where image is product property for image, indeed.